# Where should i put my hands when praying

Tags: salat, obligation

When praying, there are alot of views as to where you should put your hands in prayer, please calrify, ps. No fights!just clear answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting the hands on the stomach or chest while praying salat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/putting-the-hands-on-the-stomach-or-chest-while-praying-salat)

Comment: Please stop vandalizing the site. You can not delete you questions once they have been answered, because it is unfair to the people who have expended their time and effort to answer it. You may however have your account deleted and the question disassociated from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to sahih hadith like this one:

> *Narrated Tawus:*
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to place his right hand on his left
>   hand, then he folded them strictly on his **chest** in prayer.
>
> *Grade : Sahih (Al-Albani)*
>
> **Sunan Abi Dawud, In-book reference (Kitab Al-Salat): Book 2, Hadith 369**

Hands will be on the chest.

Answer (score 0):

I put my hands ( the right hand above the left hand) above my diaphragm between your chest, right above your upper two abdominal muscles.

> That was narrated from ‘Ali, Abu Hurayrah, al-Nakha’i, Abu Majlaz, Sa’eed ibn Jubayr, al-Thawri, al-Shaafa’i and ashaab al-ra’i. It was also narrated by Ibn al-Mundhir from Maalik.

Source:

https://islamqa.info/en/59957